# Is there a need for Assemblies in Web.config file

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-assembly

In my Web.config file there are references to the following assemblies:

```
<add assembly="UODOTNET, Version=2.2.5.7444, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=335F3FBD4BE82339"/>
<add assembly="System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
<add assembly="System.Runtime.Serialization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
<add assembly="System.Security, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
<add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
<add assembly="System.Data.Entity.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
<add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
<add assembly="System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
<add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
<add assembly="System.Xml.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
<add assembly="System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
<add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
```

Other than the first entry `UODOTNET`, which is a .DLL files that I am specifically making use of in my code, what is the need to specify them here?

If I remove them from the `Web.config` file, my website appears to run just fine without them.

Comment: you question title `Need for Assemblies in Web.config file` what need ? :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those assemblies belong to the .Net Framework and the according entries will be set in your **global machine.config** and **global web.config** too. As all config files will be summed up on start there is no need for these entries in your application.

**Example for WebApps**

`machine.config`   global machine.config in your current .net framework folder

plus

`web.config`                  global web.config - for all webApplications in your current .net fx folder

plus

`web.config`                  your webSites config file

results in your configuration. Your current .net framework folder is something like

```
   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\CONFIG
```

according to your **target framework** *(1.0, 1.1 ... )* and **plattform** *(x86, x64)*